# implementation of fm transmitter

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on signal processing section.
I want develop fm transmitter (only fm modulation) using Java (because I have been recording and play back audio data using Java). I want modulate this data. I have tried some functions but it is not working as follows :

```
for(int t=0;t<=1000000;t++){
  int fc=1000000;
  int fm=10000;
  double pi= 3.14;

  double b=2*Math.cos(2*pi*fm*t);
  double y=Math.sin(2*pi*fc*t+(b));///fm modulation equation
  // System.out.println(y);
  // array[t] = y;

  //
}
```

Comment: "it not working " What is it supposed to do? What is it doing instead?

Comment: did u tried to generate sine wave ? using same code actually in this code the value of b is sine wav i have plaoted this that i perfectlly gives sine wave

Comment: for fm modulation we need to create first oscillator with 90 degree phase shist signal